# Class instance mutability issue

Tags: python, class-method

I'm defining classes that pass arguments through index notation. To do this, I use the `__class_getitem__` method. Here is my implementation.

```
    def __class_getitem__(cls, parameters):
        if type(parameters) != tuple:
            parameters = (parameters,)

        if len(parameters) > 2:
            raise TypeError("Expected 2 arguments: List[sub_type, max_length]")
        if len(parameters):
            cls.sub_type = parameters[0]
        if len(parameters) > 1:
            cls.max_len = parameters[1]

        if cls.max_len <= 0:
            raise TypeError(f"Max Length of {cls.max_len} is less than or equal to 0")

        return cls
```

This class implements `List`, which can be used as `List[Int, 10]`, denoting a list of length 10 with all ints. The issue I'm seeing is that the `cls` returned is mutable.

If I instantiated two instances:

```
x = List[Int,1] 
y = List[Int,10]
```

Both classes' attribute `max_len` will be set to 10. I tried to return an instantiated class, i.e., `cls ()`, but with the same result.

It makes sense that the non-instantiated instance is the same object, but if they return an instantiated class, I don't understand why they are the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you want the variable to be attached to the *instance*, then use an instance variable rather than a class variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, class variables are shared by all instances of a class. So it follows that all of your instances will have the class variables from the most recent alteration. Secondly, you are mistaken that you have instantiated the class in your example. Instantiation occurs when you call a class (`MyClass()`), or more specifically, there are two magic methods `__new__` and `__init__` that perform the process. You have neither called the class nor those methods, therefore no instantiation has occurred.

Does this help?

Comment: Yes, I understand that I have not instantiated the class in my example above. However, if I replaced `return cls`, with `return cls()` I will have, correct?

Comment: Yes, but it will still have the same class variables as all of the other instances. This is just how class variables work, you seem to want instance variables for this purpose, which you can assign in the `__init__` method.

Comment: But can instance variables be modified in a class method? I.e. `cls.sub_type = ...`

Comment: no, because your class method will need to have instance referemce, which is what `self` is for. You do not have `self` here but `cls` instead. Either one, or another. Alternatively you could make class method requiring instance as tjhe argument but that sounds like nonsense here. I'd probably help if you tell what you want to acheive by all this.

Comment: I am using these as a replacement for Python types. The idea is that I can annotate functions with these "types" and randomly generate arguments to pass to the function. For examples, `List[Int | Str, 10]` will generate a bunch of lists that have maximum size 10 and whose members are of type int or of type string.

Comment: Using instance variables works just fine for this, except for when the types are annotated as such: `l : List`, which denotes a list made up of any types and is a valid annotation. There, I will need to provide `self` to the `generate` method.

Comment: And I would also need `sub_type` and `max_len` to be instantiated somehow. I suppose if there was a way to detect that the annotation was being used in an uninstantiated form, I could just instantiate it with `List[None]`.

Answer (score 1):

I got a feeling you got tricked by the name `class variable` or something around there. In Python that means that the variable is shared across **all instances of given class**, and while both `x` and `y` are instance of the same `List` class, they **both** use **the same** `max_len` and `sub_type`. So no matter how many instances you create, the last one's values will be what all the instances will be using. Therefore I'd say you wanted regular instance variables instead.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However, can I modify the instance variables from a class method? i.e. cls.sub_type = ...?